# wait the end of a forEach on a javaStream

Tags: java, asynchronous

I'm in JDK 11,
I have this:

```
 @Async("somegthing")
public void process(Some some) {...}

...
{ 
  list.stream()
    .someOperationWhoCanOnlyBeDoneOneAStream()
    .forEach(::process);

  someOtherMethod();
 }
```

I need to wait the end of the foreach before launching someOtherMethod.
 How do I do it?
I think it' obvious, but I don't have any skills in asynchroneuous

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods how you can do it:

```
 import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
 ....
 @Async("somegthing")
 public void process(Some some) {...}

 ...
 { 
      CompletableFuture<String> task = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
       list.stream()
         .someOperationWhoCanOnlyBeDoneOneAStream()
         .forEach(::process);
         return "completed";
      });
       task.thenAccept(finres -> {
        someOtherMethod();
      });
 }
```

Comment: If i put the whole thing in a test, the test end before the "thenAccept"